# Best practice to show search result in a popup modal in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

I am passing a value (search string) from a form to a controller action method where I perform some activities to find specific records from the db then passing the result to either ViewBag or to a model in order to display the result in a view.

The easy way is to pass the result as a model (or viewmodel) to the view .. something like:

1- Pass the string from a form to the controller.

2- in the controller, method, after performing the search and saving it to a list/var ..

return View(mymodel);

3- in the view .. we can say

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
... table here to display the columns and the data..etc.
}

The question is, in stead of the view, how can I display the result in a modal popup ?

There are so many suggestions with many different JQuery or JavaScripts but is there any easier solution?

is there anything like (simply) show me the view in a popup modal ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there anything like (simply) show me the view in a popup modal ?

I think the simpest way to display the result in a modal popup is using **partial view and ajax**.

Here, you cannot avoid creating a view to store the content that needs to be displayed in the modal popup. Of course, you only need to create a **partial view** instead of a view.

Here is a simple demo for your reference:

main view:

### Update:

```
   @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Testpop";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <h1>Testpop</h1>
    
    <form>
        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="showPop">Open Modal</button>
    
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog   modal-lg">
    
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body ">
                        <div id="popup">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="submitModal">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </form>
    
    @section Scripts{
        <script>
            $('#showPop').click(function () {
                 var url = '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Default")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { "para": $("#Text1").val()},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#popup').html(data);
                    }
                });
            })

$('#submitModal').click(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "Default")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                data: { "data": $("input[name='data']").val() },
                success: function () {
                    $("#Text1").val("");
                    alert("pass successfully!");
                   
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    }
```

Default/GetPartialView action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetPartialView(string para)
        {
             //get data
            var model = _context.Person.Where(x=>x.Name == para).ToList();
            return PartialView("_PopView",model);
        }
```

_PopView.cshtml partial view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Person>
    
    
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Nome_Tipo</td>
        </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Nome_Tipo
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" />
```

pop up submit data to the action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetData(string data)
        {
            //do anything.
            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is the new result:
[image]

Comment: Perfect .. this is exactly what I was looking for.. thank you sooo much

Comment: Dear Yongqing Yu, what if in the popup modal I have a simple form that contains a text box and a button to submit the value of the text box to a controller, method to store the content of the text box in a table ? I mean to have a simple form below the displayed table (between Id 3 and the close button)? I tried to have a form tag inside the partial view to target the controller but it didn't work

Comment: @user3208728, if you directly add form in the partial view, it does not work. To achieve your function, you should put the submit button in the modal pop up in main view instead of partial view, and you need to use ajax to pass data to the action in js , I have updated my reply, you can refer to it.

Comment: @user3208728, if my reply helped you solve your issue, please accept it as the answer, which will help others who have the same issue.

Comment: I am very sorry .. didn't notice that .. done now .. thanks again